# ml.net sentiment analysis build generates Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ml.net

I have installed VS2017 ver. 15.7.5 and followed the instructions to build the SentimentAnalysis project as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis.  When I try to debug the code, I get "Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'.  The address is not valid for this context."  Any suggestions on what to try to overcome this hurdle?

Answer (score 0):

Possible case of Component Cache issue. One way to fix this is as suggested below.

> **On Visual Studio 2017**

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache directory`
3. Restart Visual Studio.

> **On Visual Studio 2015**

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory`
3. Restart Visual Studio.

> **On Visual Studio 2013**

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache directory`
3. Restart Visual Studio.

---

PS: Source of information as found [Here](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md)

Comment: The directory 15.0 directory is empty, so there is nothing to delete.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SaulN do you see any other folder along with 15.0 ? and anything starting with 15.0... I have something like 15.0_49c5511c

Comment: There are a number of directories that start with 15.  I tried deleting the ComponentModelCache directory of one of them an VS wouldn't restart.

Comment: Running the program without debugging (ctrl+F5) produces the results described in the tutorial.  Running it with debugging (F5) produces the problem.

Comment: @SaulN in that case can you try to run VS as administrator ? I doubt that you have installed the VS using admin account and now working with a different account. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @SaulN any update? where you able to resolve the issue ?